# empty checkpoint files for azure eventhub

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-eventhub-client

I am using `BlobCheckpointStore` to do checkpoint for azure eventhub using the official tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/eventhub-checkpointstoreblob-readme?view=azure-python#consume-events-using-a-blobcheckpointstore-to-do-checkpoint

But then when I checked my blob storage where the checkpoint files are held, it only has two folders: `checkpoint` and `ownership` each of which contains empty files with files name like `0`, `1`, etc.
In this case, how the offsets and sequence numbers are stored if they are all empty files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blobs are intentionally empty.  Checkpoint and ownership information is stored as metadata attributes on the blobs rather than content.  This allows us to read the data without having to download the content and deserialize or parse the resulting text.